# All I know (how/what) to do

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language, logic

Below are three examples:

- That's all I know to do.
- That's all I know how to do.
- That's all I know what to do.

Which of the three is the most idiomatic way of expressing the idea that what was mentioned was all that I can do, since I don't know how to do anything else.
To me, 'how to do' sounds the most natural but lacks logic, since it's about WHAT I can do and not HOW I do them.
Also, as much as I am tempted to go with 'All I know to do', isn't the verb 'know' usually not followed by infinitives?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> That's all I know about it.

would be the general idiomatic expression to say you have a limited knowledge about the subject.

> That's all I know *(about)* how to do *(it)*.

would mean you have limited knowledge on "how" to do *something*

> That's all I know *(about)* what to do.

would mean you have limited knowledge on "what" needs to be done in a situation.

Comment: You added "about" where the poster made no mention of the word. that changes the meaning somewhat. I'm not sure that's what they were asking.

Comment: That's right. Thanks for the input Peter but I am looking at an expression that relates to what someone knows to do, not what they know about a certain subject.

Answer (score 0):

All three are okay, but they are used in different contexts.

```
That's all I know to do
```

This one is for when you are speaking about your knowledge of which options you have. As in, "I can't think of anything else to try."

```
That's all I know how to do
```

This is for speaking about your knowledge of certain actions. As in, "I don't know how to do anything else. Therefore, there's nothing more I can try."

```
That's all I know what to do
```

This is is pretty much the same as the first, but it's not used this way in standard English. It is chiefly a variant of certain dialects within England, and frankly is probably not very common there either. Since I'm Canadian, I can't speak much to English dialects outside my area. Perhaps an English user could give a clearer answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

1. List item

All the sentences are grammatical.

That's all I know to do/That's all I know what to do.

Both the sentences have the same meaning, that is, I don't know there's more to do than I told you.

That's all I know how to do.

That's a different meaning. It means "I don't know more than I told you how to do".

Comment: I can't pinpoint the rule that would make it ungrammatical, but "that's all I know what to do" sounds very unnatural and would at least get a raised eyebrow from me if somebody said it.

Comment: @Emmabee, I am sorry. It's a typo.